# Amazon Cloud Media Server Streaming Help

Tags: stream, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, flash-media-server

Can someone PLEASE help me with setting up Adobe Media Server Streaming on Amazon Cloud?

I am reading whole day about it, about how to set it up on "regular" machines, but I can't find anywhere how to configure it on Amazon Cloud... After whole day reading I can say that I am still at start, don't know anything, and totally lost...

Can someone just point me in right direction? I don't know anything about Cloud servers, and working with this platforms...

So can anyone just point me where to start?

I need Adobe Media Server Live Streaming for HTML5 streams... I know HTML5, know how to make video element and everything, but I don't know how to start server...

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using HTML5, you will not be able to use the RTMP streaming type in cloudfront.  Don't worry about using the Adobe Media, or anything like that.  Just look at hosting the files in S3 first, get the files loaded to that and pull them down in your HTML5  tag.  Then, if you want cloudfront, you can easily add that and use that moving forward.

If you end up using a flash client to play the video, like the JW player, you could then setup a streaming cloudfront instance and utilize the RTMP streaming.

Comment: New Adobe Media Server has ability to stream live content to HTML5... I am not streaming already existing files, I want to have live stream from users cams to another users online watching it in HTML5 video...

Comment: Ok, live streaming, S3 and cloudfront will not be an option.  You'll need to create a new server instance in EC2, and install the Adobe Media Server.  Another good option is Wowza Media server.

Comment: Can you help me with that, please? Like creating step-by-step what to do? Since I am reading this whole day, yesterday and today, and still can't find anything where to start... I even ask theirs admins, but they just ignore me... I post question inside theirs forum and they also ignored me... I don't know what to do... :/

Comment: I don't have a step by step guide, however, this can help you, you'll need to do more research on your own to finalize it, but I know this works fine, and gives you many stream options.  http://www.wowza.com/quickstart_EC2.html

Comment: @SharkTheDark: If you found a good tutorial, could you please provide me the link?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to only stream existing content, [AWS CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) runs Adobe Media Servers for files stored in S3 at no additional cost. The CloudFront term for using their Adobe Media Servers is "Streaming Distributions".

The [Getting Started with CloudFront](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/GettingStartedGuide/StartingCloudFront.html) guide outlines setting up up streaming distributions. The [Where Do I Go From Here page](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/GettingStartedGuide/WhereGoFromHere.html) has links to several how-to articles.

Comment: No, no, it's not existing content, I want live streaming, live broadcasting from one users to another visitor users...